# Add success to double jquery/ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm using the following to post form data from a web app to both a server-side php and to quickbase. The fill.php processes the signature, appends it to a pdf, and emails the result.

Everything works fine, except I have no real success functions for this part:

```
$('#sendbtn').click(function(){

    signatures();

    $.post( 'https://www.quickbase.com/db/dbname?act=API_AddRecord', $('form').serialize());

    $.post( 'fill.php', $('form').serialize(), $.mobile.changePage('#successpop', {transition: 'pop', role: 'dialog'}));

});
```

The pop-up displays, but its not a true indicator of any success. How can I get a response back from one or both of these posts before displaying the success pop-up? It'd be great to conditionally go from one to the other post on success, but I'm not as worried about the QuickBase post. I definitely need to confirm the fill.php post before displaying success.

What I like about this is that it avoids a redirect to a url outside my app.

Thanks for any help!!

```
<form action="" encoding='multipart/form-data' encType='multipart/form-data'>
<input type=text name=_fid_6 >
<input type=text name=_fid_7 >
<input type=text name=_fid_8 >
<input type="hidden" name="img" id="img" />
<input type="button" value="Sign!" id="sendbtn" />
</form>  

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#signature").jSignature()
            })
            function signatures(){
                var $sigdiv = $("#signature");
                var datax = $sigdiv.jSignature("getData","image");
                $('#img').val(datax);
                $sigdiv.jSignature("reset")
            }
        </script>

<script>
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#sendbtn').click(function(){

        signatures();

        $.post( 'https://www.quickbase.com/db/dbname?act=API_AddRecord', $('form').serialize());

        $.post( 'fill.php', $('form').serialize(), $.mobile.changePage('#successpop', {transition: 'pop', role: 'dialog'}));

    });
});
</script>

<div data-role="page" id="successpop">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="c">
<h1>QAF Sent</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content" data-theme="d">    
<h2>Your QAF has been sent</h2> 
<p><input type="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" value="Begin New QAF" data-icon="back" onclick="clearForm();"/></p>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of these $.post()s will complete first and one will complete second.  You don't necessarily know which so set a global variable (like a Boolean) that is set to true on the completion of the first and then add a check for true.  When the success function that sees the value as true have it call a onDoubleSuccess() function. Like so ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qtTn6/1/)):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready( function(){
    $('#sendbtn').click(function(){
      var finishedFirstPost = false,
      onDoubleSuccess = function() {
        //code goes here
        $.mobile.changePage('#successpop', {transition: 'pop', role: 'dialog'});
      };
      signatures();
      $.post(
        'https://www.quickbase.com/db/dbname?act=API_AddRecord',
        $('form').serialize(),
        function() {
          if(finishedFirstPost) {
            onDoubleSuccess();
          } else {
            finishedFirstPost = true;
          }
        });
      $.post(
        'fill.php',
        $('form').serialize(),
        function() {
          if(finishedFirstPost) {
            onDoubleSuccess();
          } else {
            finishedFirstPost = true;
          }
        });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Also you can't do an HTTP POST to an external domain without [CORS support](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) so you should change the Quickbase `$.post()` to `$.get()`.  Here is the [API documentation](http://www.quickbase.com/api-guide/add_record.html) showing that this shoudl work.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! Is there a way to display a simple error message if either post fails?

Comment: You can always add a failure function if you switch from $.post() to the more powerful [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Thanks. I experimented with $.ajax() - trying to nest the 2nd post inside the success function of the 1st, but it wasn't working. Good to know that failure doesn't work with $.post()

Comment: Hmm. I actually haven't been able to get the initial answer to work. Just hangs indefinitely.

Comment: This is because you are HTTP posting to an external domain (so it's throwing a failure event)  You want to replace your $.post() to QuickBase  with a $.get()

Comment: Don't use a global variable, just put the variable within the click handler.  It will be available to both success functions while not polluting the global scope.

Comment: There's no need for `$.ajax()` just to add an error handler.  You can use an error handler with `$.post()` like so: `$.post(...).error(function errHandler(xhr, status, message) { ... })`.